# How can I know the path to my python exe in docker

Tags: python, c#, .net, docker

I have a C# program which should run a python program for me. For that I need to know the path to my python.exe. The program is called in my docker container.

This is the python part of my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.7-slim-stretch

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir argparse torch torchvision requests bytesbufio
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/example/path"
COPY program.py ./
```

My C# code can not find this path. The python script is in the same folder as my C# function.

C# code:

```
public double EstimatePopularity(String input)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("."));
            var path = ".";
            start.FileName = @"example/path/python.exe";
            start.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", "program.py", input);
            start.UseShellExecute = false;
            start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            start.RedirectStandardError = true;
            using(Process? process = Process.Start(start))
            {
                using(StreamReader? reader = process?.StandardOutput)
                {
                    double result = Convert.ToDouble(reader?.ReadToEnd());
                    return result;
                }
            }
    
        }
```

This is the error I get:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
```

Comment: Isn't that a Linux-based container image? Is your code also running in the Docker container? It doesn't look like it is? If it isn't, it won't have access to the file system of the container.

Comment: Judging by the [layers](https://hub.docker.com/layers/python/library/python/3.7.7-slim-stretch/images/sha256-6ab3f1b840fb9757c8fb240c2eb63458b4ff503894a96cc4f10a36286f8acf75?context=explore), it seems that the `python3` executable is in `/usr/local/bin/`, so the full path including the executable name is `/usr/local/bin/python3` Do note that this is _inside the container_, not on your host machine.

Comment: As long as the executable is in your $PATH (in this case it is), you can run `docker exec <container> which python` (or docker run if the container isn't currently running) to print the absolute path of it and copy that into your code.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. It is Linux based. And I am also calling dotnet run in my docker file, that's how the c# code gets executed and I see the error. I think the path to the python.exe is correct now. Something else might through that error